# Prove the two form of Banach-Steinhaus theorem are equivalent (uniformly boundedness)

Tags: real-analysis

1st form of the theorem:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a normed vector space. Let $\{T_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of bounded operators i.e.$\{T_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}\subseteq \mathbb B(X,Y)$.Then we have two conditions:

a) there exists a generic set $G\subseteq X$ so that $\sup_{\alpha \in A} ||T_{\alpha}x||=+\infty$ $\forall x \in G$

b) $\sup_{\alpha \in A} ||T_{\alpha}x||<+\infty$

2nd form:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a normed vector space. Let $\{T_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of bounded operators i.e.$\{T_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}\subseteq \mathbb B(X,Y)$ and suppose that there exists $E\subseteq X$ of second category so that $\sup_{\alpha \in A} ||T_{\alpha}x||<+\infty \quad \forall x \in E$. Then $\sup_{\alpha \in A} ||T_{\alpha}x||<+\infty$

The 2nd implies the 1st is obvious. In fact if $M=\sup_{\alpha \in A} 
||T_{\alpha}||<\infty$

then $\sup_{\alpha \in A} ||T_{\alpha}x||<\infty \quad \forall x \in X$ 
because $||T_{\alpha}x||\le||T_{\alpha}||\quad  ||x||$

How can I prove 1st form  implies 2nd form?

Comment: What do you mean by Generic set?

Comment: A generic set is the complementary of a set of  first category and exists $\{V_n\}$ dense open so that $\cap V_n \subseteq G$